# How does Machine Learning Links with Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

ML deals with the learning of the machines based upon its experiences or a given set of supervision and we can analyse data based upon the ML algorithms and Hadoop is software framework for storage and large-scale processing of data-sets on clusters of commodity hardware. So my question is:

1. How does ML gets linked with Hadoop ?
2. How are they used together? or
3. Do I have the wrong understanding of these things?

Comment: Have a look at Apache Mahout.

Comment: Hadoop may help a little bit in processing data for training and preparing decision trees(using some algorithms and custom software) besides that I see no connection.

Comment: Ironically though, Apache Mahout is migrating from Hadoop to Spark.

Comment: @Chiron  What's the Spark? A Micro Framework for java?

Comment: @ajkumar25 Check Apache Spark project. http://spark.apache.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ML works with data, nowadays data got big, so ML connected to big data. Hadoop helps to do processing on big data, so this is the connection between Hadoop and ML.
2. See [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/), works specifically for clustering, classification and ... (currently) based on Hadoop.
3. No you're not.

Comment: Mahout will not base on Hadoop in the near future. They are migrating to Apache Spark.